# How to show a widget only when user is scrolling?

Tags: scroll, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to hide buttons on screen and show them after user starts scrolling till for the 5 seconds from the last scroll.

I've wrapped my `SingleChildScrollView` with `GestureDetector` and change the visibility value from `onTap` callback to hide my buttons with `Visibility` widget. However, there is no event like onScroll on `GestureDetector`.

Is there anyone who succesfully implement that effect or is there any built-in animation for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, there aren't any `onScroll` events on `GestureDetector`, but there are `onVerticalDrag` events, which are basically the same, with another name.

But, for that, you don't actually need a `GestureDetector`. You can listen to the scroll changes, handling the `ScrollStartNotification` and `ScrollEndNotification` notifications with a `NotificationListener`, since you are already using a `SingleChildScrollView`.

I've created a little example to show you that which will produce the following: 
On scroll a flag to display the button is set to `true` and at the end, it will reset back to `false` and rebuild the tree with no button after 5 seconds if no more scroll notifications come in between (that's the reason why you don't set the `_buttonShowing = false` after the `Future` completes but before.

[image: example]

```
bool _buttonShowing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> columnWidgets = List<Widget>.filled(100, Container(height: 100.0, child: Placeholder()));

    if (_buttonShowing) {
      columnWidgets = List.from(columnWidgets)
        ..insert(
            3, Visibility(child: RaisedButton(child: Text('Press me'), onPressed: () {}), visible: _buttonShowing));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
          if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
            if (!_buttonShowing) {
              setState(() => _buttonShowing = true);
            }
          } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
            if (_buttonShowing) {
              _buttonShowing = false;
              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) => setState(() {}));
            }
          }
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: columnWidgets),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, those properties seems to will work. However it locks my UI if I wrap GestureDetector with SingleChildScrollView, like in your example, and If I wrap my SingleChildScrollView with GestureDetector, nothing happens.

Comment: Actually you don't need a `GestureDetector` for that. By using only a `SingleChildScrollView` and a `NotificationListener` to handle the notifications that you need (start and end) you should be fine. I've edited my answer accordingly and provided a little example.

Comment: Its working but when there are not enough items to scroll, the buttons don't show up. I guess it doesn't render SingleChildScrollView if it isn't needed. 
And when there is enough items to scroll, the buttons show only for once. Any idea?

Comment: `SingleChildScrollView` won't scroll if you actually don't need a scroll. You shouldn't expect a user to start scrolling if the screen is already displaying all of its content so you shouldn't rely on scroll to display the button for that scenario IMO.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have to find another solution.